# Ng-if - Try to get data of my Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have a number in my Firebase and I want to get it in my ng-if.

I've try a Snapshot, my console log display good value but it's seems to be ignore by ng-if.

Maybe I've miss something ...

My Ng-If :

```
<div class="item" ng-if="distanceTo(event) < dist ">
```

My JS :

```js
userRef.child($scope.currentUser.authResponse.userID)
       .child("settings")
       .child("distance")
       .once('value', function(snap) {

  console.log(snap.val())
  $scope.dist = snap.val()
  console.log($scope.dist)

})

$scope.distanceTo = function(event) { 
  var distance = GreatCircle.distance(event.addressid.geometry.location.H, 
                                      position.longitude, 
                                      position.latitude, 
                                      event.addressid.geometry.location.L ) 
  event.distance = distance 
  distance = distance.toFixed(1) 
  return distance 
};
```

```html
<div class="item" ng-if="distanceTo(event) < dist ">
```

Comment: Can you add your code for `distanceTo`? I mean, add it to your question.

Comment: $scope.distanceTo = function(event) {
      var distance = GreatCircle.distance( 
        event.addressid.geometry.location.H, 
        position.longitude, 
        position.latitude, 
        event.addressid.geometry.location.L
      )
      event.distance = distance
      distance = distance.toFixed(1)
      return distance
    };

Comment: But when I replace "dist" by a number, it's work ...

Comment: Is `console.log(snap.val())` happening?

Comment: I have the good number in console log ...

Comment: It's because Angular doesn't know when the Firebase listener gets updated. My answer shows you how to fix :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the Angular is unaware of when your Firebase listener gets updated. You have two options: use `$timeout` (not recommend), or use AngularFire (highly, highly recommend).

With `$timeout` you would do something like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>');
  // get the user
  $scope.currentUser = ref.getUser();
  var userRef = ref.child($scope.currentUser.uid).child("settings/distance");
  userRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.dist = snap.val();
    });
  });
});
```

With AngularFire, this is much, much easier:

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase']) // include AngularFire
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>');
  $scope.dist = $firebaseObject(ref);
});
```

[Check out the AngularFire quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html) to get up and running and save yourself a lot of time and agony :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I create ref to my path : userRef.child($scope.currentUser.authResponse.userID).child("settings").child("distance") ?

Comment: If you are authenticated, you get can get the user by calling `ref.getAuth()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I mean with AngularFire, if it's much easier I want to try it ! :)

Comment: You totally should! AngularFire is a set of services for synchronizing collections of data. Each service just takes in a Firebase reference, so you would create a reference how you normally would. Except you don't have to create the listener yourself, AngularFire takes care of that for you. It's also officially supported by Firebase and worked on by Firebase engineers.

Comment: I will test it now, but I don't know how can I make reference to my path with AngularFire, I have habits with Firebase only ...

Comment: You don't make a reference with AngularFire. You make a reference with the regular Firebase SDK and then pass it to AngularFire.

Comment: Like it ? :
    var distRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users" + $scope.currentUser.uid + "settings/distance" )
    $scope.dist = $firebaseObject(distRef);

Comment: Yes :). But use .child() instead of string concatenation, it's less error prone that way.

Comment: I have this error : error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

Comment: That means you have an object with a cyclical reference. This is JavaScript constraint not an AngularFire error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97453/discussion-between-yngdev31-and-david-east).

Comment: If my solution helped, can you please mark it as accepted? It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: Go to chat I answer you the problem are always here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `distanceTo` function is working ok (I was not able to test that so I mocked it), the problem lies in the fact that `$scope.dist` is not getting set.

Check which of your `console.log`s are happening. I suspect they are not happening. Therefore, the problem lies in the line

```
userRef.child($scope.currentUser.authResponse.userID).child("settings").child("distance").once('value',
```

Also I noticed you don't use semi-colons. That's not a good practice and for all I know might be contributing to the problem.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.distanceTo = function(event) {
      return 10;
      var distance = GreatCircle.distance(event.addressid.geometry.location.H, position.longitude, position.latitude, event.addressid.geometry.location.L);
      event.distance = distance;
      distance = distance.toFixed(1);
      return distance;
    };



    /*    userRef.child($scope.currentUser.authResponse.userID).child("settings").child("distance").once('value', function(snap) {

          console.log(snap.val())
          $scope.dist = snap.val()
          console.log($scope.dist)

        });
    */
  }
]);
```

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
input {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="dist = 10">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type=text ng-model="dist" placeholder="values > 10 will make the item show" />
  <div class="item" ng-if="distanceTo(event) < dist ">
</body>

</html>
```